# Kernel Compiling Error vmlinux error 1 in virtualbox

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I want to add new system call in my linux kernel

After doing the steps 
I tried to compile my linux kernel in virtualbox

However, after I enter this command

```
$ make
```

It worked for about 2 hours but suddenly I got this error

```
scripts/link-vmlinux.sh: line 52:  4183 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) 
${LD} ${LDFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS_vmlinux} -o ${2} -T ${lds} 
${KBUILD_VMLINUX_INIT} --start-group ${KBUILD_VMLINUX_MAIN}
 --end-group ${1}
rm: cannot remove ‘.old_version’: Read-only file system
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

my kernel is linux-4.4.3 and I use Ubuntu

I am still new to linux, virtualbox and kernel so I hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error you got:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘.old_version’: Read-only file system
make: *** [vmlinux] Error 1
```

The partition is mounted as read only. You can try remounting it with rw flags.